# Add Dynamic DropDown to HTML form by using StringBuilder in C# [that works with C# codebehind]

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net

here I wanna add a dynamic dropdowns as a table in a html document, and I want to bind that dropdown with values of my SQLSERVER table column. once I finally choose the values in dropdown want to **retrieve** those selected values/text back to ma SqlServer.
please help me to finish this,
I also post ma codebehind with this question..

```cs
        protected void txtcreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DropDownList dl = new DropDownList();
            int roomno = Convert.ToInt16(txtroom.Text);
            int panno = Convert.ToInt16(txtpan.Text);
            StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
            str.Append("<table>");

            for(int row = 0; row < roomno; row++)
            { str.Append("<tr>");
                for(int col = 0; col < panno; col++)
                {
                    dt = new DataTable();
                    str.Append("<td>");
                    dl.ID = "dd" + row.ToString() + col.ToString();
                    dt = sp.showStudent();
                    dl.DataSource = dt;
                    dl.DataTextField = "name";
                    dl.DataBind();
                    str.Append(dl);
                    str.Append("</td>");
                    ph.Controls.Add(dl);
                }
                str.Append("</tr>");
            }
            str.Append("</table>");
            
            ltr.Text = str.ToString();
        }
    }
```

and the **aspx** file is

```html
     <form id="form1" runat="server">
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtroom" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:TextBox ID="txtpan" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><asp:Button ID="txtcreate" runat="server" OnClick="txtcreate_Click" Text="Button" />
            <center>
        <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="grid" AutoGenerateColumns="true" runat="server">
              
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>     
    
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ph" runat="server">
                    <asp:Literal ID="ltr" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                </asp:PlaceHolder>
            </center>
        </form>
```

thanks guys...